# using the http headers in requests module python

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests

Would it be possible to specify the source address of a request by specifying the value of the source ip address in one of the headers?
Can the From field be used for this purpose?

My code so far:

```
import requests


response = requests.get('http://server_ip/file_name',headers={"From":"source_ip"}, stream=True)  
handle = open('/home/client1/test/try101.txt', "wb")
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        handle.write(chunk)
```

The From field does not seem to be working for this purpose? Is there another field for this purpose? Or another alternative to achieve this task?

Comment: The Source header field is for the eMail address. Why do you want to send the source iP address in the http header?

Comment: i want to generate each request from a different source ip address.Currently i am generating temporary ips by using the ip address add command.

Comment: Would there be any way to do this?